# SSRS - Report Builder 3.0 - This Day Last Year

Tags: reporting-services, report, reporting, builder

I'm trying to get a Today vs This Day Last Year Comparison Report sorted.

I set a `'From'` and `'To'` date based on a `'Preset'` parameter.

So if it is set to `'This Week'` it sets the start date to Monday and the end date to Sunday.

What I want now is a Today vs This Day Last Year. So for example, if i were to do it for today, I would get `09/04/2015` vs `10/04/2014`. So as today is Thursday, I want the nearest Thursday from `09/04/2014`.

Also want the same for `'Yesterday'`. `So 08/04/2015` vs `09/04/2014`

Is there a way to do this in either the Parameters SSRS expression, or within the custom 'Code' section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get this day last year, you can just subtract 52 weeks from today. Try this expression: =DateAdd("ww",-52,Today()). Likewise you can subtract 1 day from today to get yesterday: =DateAdd("d",-1,Today()).

Comment: I needed say if today was a Tuesday, the same Tuesday of last year. I've sussed it now with some clever VB